# How to pass an array to a jquery script from a codeigniter view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using the jquery datatables plugin and codeigniter. In one of my views I have:

```
 <table id="myDataTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <?php foreach($keys as $key): ?>
            <th><?php echo $key; ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>


        </tr>

      </thead>      
            <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'datatable_controller/datatable',
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "message_id" },
                    { "data": "subject" },
                    { "data": "date" }
                  ],
```

in reference to the columns structure, right now I am hard coding in column field names (id, message-id,subject , date ) . I already have these in an array $keys, which I am using above to dynamically generate the table HTML. Is there a way to pass $keys directly into the "columns" option?

Comment: Any reason not to use json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use the PHP loop inside the "columns" option in your javascript, if I'm following the format correctly.  Something like this (untested obviously)?

```
      "columns": [
               <?php foreach($keys as $key): ?>
                 {"data": "<?php echo $key ?>"},
               <?php endforeach; ?>
              ],
```